# How do I reduce the file size of a jpeg image?

Tags: jpeg

I have a photo in jpeg format that I am unable to reduce from 110 KB to 45kb. What software can do this?

Comment: I can reduce just about any JPEG to an arbitrarily small size by reducing it to a size of 1 pixel x 1 pixel. What constraints do you have which prevent you from doing this?

Comment: To expand on what Philip is asking: What are you using this image for? What are the pixel dimensions of the image, and can those be reduced? 45kb is rather small, especially for a photograph.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really more about general image manipulation than photography. Could be a good candidate for Superuser.

Comment: Use IrfanView and save image at a lower quality.

Comment: This question has also been asked almost ad nauseam in the past.

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61039/how-can-i-target-a-specific-size-in-megabytes-when-saving-a-jpeg-in-photoshop/61041#61041

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11638/how-to-reduce-the-file-size-of-my-photos-to-under-15-mb/11748#11748

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/56329/15871

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/16631/15871

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/52012/15871

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/30490/15871

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the quality, then it becomes smaller. For this you can use GIMP, Photoshop, ..

Are you sure that you need such a bad quality?